# How to fix _TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Widget')?

Tags: flutter, function, widget, typeerror

I want to create functions that run tasks like adding a value to a list, but don't return anything. When I try doing that with the code below, I keep getting _TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Widget') after I call addToList() in the Widget build code block. My goal is to first add values to a list, then remove duplicates from the list, and then order the list from earliest time to latest time. I'd appreciate any help! Below is the code for my functions and the Widget build code block:

````
addToList()
      if (dbc != false) {
        times.add(dbc2);
      };
      if (ssc!= false) {
        times.add(ssc2);
      };
      if (egc!= false) {
        times.add(egc2);
      };
      if (dahc!= false) {
        times.add(dahc2);
      };
      if (gfac!= false) {
        times.add(gfac2);
      };
      if (trc!= false) {
        times.add(trc2);
      };
      if (tsnc!= false) {
        times.add(tsnc2);
      };
      if (yc!= false) {
        times.add(yc2);
      };
      if (cac != false) {
        times.add(cac2);
      };
      if (myoex!= false) {
        times.add(myoex2);
      };

removeDuplicates(l) {
      l.toSet().toList(); 
  }

  listOrder(l) {
    l.sort((a,b){
      return DateTime.parse(a).compareTo(DateTime.parse(b));
    });
  }

  matchableTimes() {
    while (i<times.length){
      time = times[0];
      if (time == dbt2) {
        dbt22 = true;
      };
      if (time == sast2 ) {
        sasc2 = true;
      };
      i++;
    }
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text('Hello!'),
        ),
      body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text(
                'Here: ',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              ),
              addToList(),
              removeDuplicates(times),
              listOrder(times),
              matchableTimes(),
                             ],
        ),
    );
  } ```
````

Answer (score 0):

you are passing a function addTodoList() in your column and that's not possible as it's not a widget

Answer (score 0):

Could you please be more clear with what you are trying to achieve. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help.

As was previously stated, the widget tree can only return Widgets. Your function  `addtoList()` doesn't return anything.

Happy to try and help you resolve your issue but you will need to be more clear.

The [Flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets-intro) have lots of useful information that I encourage you to refer to, they have certainly helped me become a better developer :)

Comment: I am trying to have the function addToList() add values to a list. But, I don't need it to return anything. I've added more code and clarifications to the question, please let me know what more information you need to help me. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes we may encounter such errors due to type mismatches. For example, a year is a number but we can ask to write by a string I mean a TEXT. In similar cases, you can use .toString. For example;

`print (mesaj); print ("Doğum yılı : "+dogumYili.toString()); print("Oran : "+oran.toString());`

Comment: There aren't any type mismatches.... I'm adding a TimeOfDay Value to a TimeOfDay list. Should I use the await keyword or something?

Answer (score -1):

Please update `addToList()` and `build()` with complete code in your question. I think I can help you. Just reply this answer if you already update that question.

Comment: I just updated the question with the complete code!

Comment: The return type of your **addToList()**, **removeDuplicates(times)**, **listOrder(times)**, and **matchableTimes()** is not a **Widget**. You must return a **Widget** if you want to put inside Column children.

Comment: I didn't know you could return a widget in a function. How do I do that?

Comment: Of course you can, example if you want to return Text widget. Just use **return Text(“Your Text”);**

Comment: Oh that makes sense! But there are red lines when I write return List<TimeOfDay> times;. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've gotten that to work now and I changed listOrder to listOrder(l) {
    l.sort((a,b){
      DateTime.parse(a).compareTo(DateTime.parse(b));
    });
    return Text('Done!');
  } but now I get error _TypeError (type '(dynamic, dynamic) => Null' is not a subtype of type '((TimeOfDay, TimeOfDay) => int)?' of 'compare'). Any way I can fix this or sort my times list from earliest to latest time in an easier way?

Comment: you return a DateTime wich is not a Widget, DateTime is not a Widget.

Comment: your **removeDuplicates()** also dit not return any Widget. All of your function/method must return a Widget. Just focus on your function bro, if your function did not return Widget it will 100% error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).